# Angular 9 & google map marker click event not working proprly

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Below is my code to initiate map and add cluster and markers. everything is working fine, but the marker click is behaving weird like the event is triggered instantly and hit API as well, but the global variables are updated after few seconds, sometime after minutes.

```
  renderMap() {

    window['initMap'] = () => {
      this.loadMap();
    };
    if (!window.document.getElementById('google-map-script')) {
      const s = window.document.createElement('script');
      s.id = 'google-map-script';
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      s.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + environment.GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY + '&callback=initMap';

      window.document.body.appendChild(s);
    } else {
      this.loadMap();
    }
  }

  loadMap() {
    const map = new window['google'].maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
      center: {lat: this.center.lat, lng: this.center.lng},
      zoom: this.zoom
    });
    const markers = this.markers.map((location, i) => {
      const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng},
        label: location.label,
        icon: 'assets/img/marker_.png',
        title: location.title,
        clickable: true
      });

      marker.addListener('click', () => {
        const m = location;
        this.customer = m;
        this.showLocation = true;
        this.loading = true;
        this.center = {
          lat: m.lat,
          lng: m.lng
        };
        this.companyService.company(m.company_id).subscribe((company: any) => {
          this.company = company;
          this.loading = false;
        }, error => {
          this.loading = false;
          console.log(error);
        });
      });
      return marker;
    });

    const markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
      {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});

  }

  ngOnInt(){
    this.renderMao();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to run the `click` callback in NgZone

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone)


marker.addListener('click', () => {
    this.zone.run(() => { 
     ...
});
```